# wp_post_delete is deleting all offices

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, wp-query

Below, I will supply the code that I am using right now to distinguish between my offices:

```
function import_offices()
{
    $log = [];
    $name = 'octopus_import_offices';
    $settings = get_settings();
    $octopus = get_octopus();
    $records = $octopus->get_all('offices', [
        'updated_at_after' => $settings['started'],
    ]);

/* Display the WP_Post object with all the offices */
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

/* Set an empty array for $offices */
$posts = [];

/* If there are more than one post, define the variable */
if (count($wp_query->posts) > 0) {
    $posts = $wp_query->posts;
}

$offices = [];
foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $octopus_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true);
    $wp_office_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_office_id', true);

    if ($octopus_id) {
        $offices[$octopus_id] = $post;
    } elseif ($wp_office_id) {
        $offices[$wp_office_id] = $post;
    } else {

    }
}

foreach ($records as $record) {

    $octopus_office_id = strtoupper(
        str_replace(
            ' ',
            '',
            trim($record->location_id) . trim($record->business_unit)
        )
    );

    if (array_key_exists($record->id, $offices)) {
        $office = $offices[$record->id];
        echo 'Found office (' . $record->name . ') in WP using Octopus ID (' . $record->id . ').<br />';
    } elseif (array_key_exists($octopus_office_id, $offices)) {
        $office = $offices[$octopus_office_id];
        update_post_meta($office->ID, '_octopus_id', $record->id);
        echo 'Found office (' . $record->name . ') in WP using PeopleSoft ID (' . $octopus_office_id . ').<br />';
    } else {
        $office = null;
        echo '<span style="color: red">The office (' . $record->name . ') has not been found.</span><br/>';

        foreach ($posts as $office) {
            $wp_office_id = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);

            if ($octopus_office_id != $wp_office_id) {
                wp_delete_post($office->ID, true);
            }
        }
    }

    /* If office exists */
    if ($office) {

        $sync = false;
        $time_changed = false;

        /* Change WP last modified timestamp to Unix */
        $wp_modified = strtotime(get_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', true));
        $wp_created = strtotime(get_post_meta($office->ID, '_created_date', true));

        /* If sync is enabled, move on */
        if (get_update_setting($office) != '0') {
            $sync = true;
        }

        /* If sync is enabled and Octopus modified timestamp doesn't matches WP */
        if ($sync & $record->updated_at != $wp_modified) {
            $time_changed = true;
        }

        /* If time has changed, update the metadata */
        if ($time_changed) {
            $wp_modified_back = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record->updated_at);
            $wp_created_back = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record->created_at);
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

I'm getting the following output on first load:

> Found office (Boston) in WP using ID (6).
>   The office (Ivern) has not been found.

Then when the following code executes:

```
if ($octopus_office_id != $wp_office_id) {
      wp_delete_post($office->ID, true);
}
```

It just deletes all the offices instead of just the offices that aren't matching as shown below:

> The office (Boston) has not been found.
>   The office (Ivern) has not been found.

How can I make it delete only the posts (offices) that aren't matching $octopus_office_id?

print_r2($wp_office_id) prints out the following:

> BUENOSAIREFHI
>   ORANGECO.HRDUS

print_r2($octopus_office_id) prints out the following:

> BUENOSAIREFHI
>   ORANGECO.FHUSA

So as shown, the BUENOSAIREFHI offices match, but the ORANGECO offices don't, I want to be able to delete just the offices that don't match.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the cause, but, there is a major assumption being made here, what if `get_post_meta` fails to retrieve the post meta? Then the office ID would be `false`, and that definitely doesn't match the ID you're checking against, so it would delete the office. This may not be the problem you're trying to solve, but it's an additional problem you were unaware of. Don't just call functions and assume they worked, check their return values for error objects and failure values

Comment: Also, where does `octopus_office_id` come from? Where does `$posts` come from? Your code is incomplete, please edit your question to include more of the code. Also, why are you deleting every office that doesn't match an ID? What problem are you trying to solve that necessitates this?

Comment: So what get_post_meta is doing now is grabbing the offices with an ID in WP which always has an ID and is being replaced by the Octopus ID.

I will update the post.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, but you should move the `$office = null;` to after the `foreach ($posts as $office) { ... }`. Also, in that `foreach`, try `var_dump( $octopus_office_id != $wp_office_id, $octopus_office_id, $wp_office_id, $office->ID ); echo '<br>'; continue;` just to see if the logic and data are good.